# Groupby id and tranpose counts of unique column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    id    task1    task2
1   A     run      eat
2   A     run      drink
3   A     walk     drink
4   B     walk     eat
5   B     jog      eat
```

and I want to turn it into

```
    id    run    walk    jog    eat    drink
1   A     2      1       0      1      2
2   B     0      1       1      2      0
```

I can do this with a very inefficient method using dictionary Counter but I'd like to know how to do this with Pandas efficiently without creating smaller DataFrames and concatenating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='id', value_vars=['task1', 'task2'])
print df

  id variable  value
0  A    task1    run
1  A    task1    run
2  A    task1   walk
3  B    task1   walk
4  B    task1    jog
5  A    task2    eat
6  A    task2  drink
7  A    task2  drink
8  B    task2    eat
9  B    task2    eat

df = pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['value']).reset_index()
df.columns.name = ''
print df

  id  drink  eat  jog  run  walk
0  A      2    1    0    2     1
1  B      0    2    1    0     1
```